# Change color when hover over element

Tags: html, css

How can you change the color of the arrow when you hover over it with a mouse?

Please refer to the code snippet I have tried to achieve this (BTW the 55.5 etc percentage is intentional), where am I going wrong?

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 55,5%;
}

.arrow-down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
  animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
  left: 48.25vw;
  bottom: -15vw;
}

.arrow-down:hover {
  color:white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.arrow-down:hover::after { ....`

Comment: So the comma is intentional?

Comment: That code does not work for me. Did I do something wrong?                             .arrow-down:hover::after {
  border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

Comment: decimal numbers are not an issue, decimal numbers with comma separator are just not correct... should use a point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 55,5%;
}

.arrow-down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
  animation: 3s arrow infinite ease;
  left: 48.25vw;
  bottom: -15vw;
}

.arrow-down:hover::after {
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down">
</div>
```

notice that arrow colors are set `::after` not on `.arrow-down`

you need to change these css styles

```
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

try this

```
.arrow-down:hover::after {
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}
```